# What time Cardano Mainnet To Be Launched?

Tags: mainnet

I am new to Cardano and I want to learn and code with it. I have search a lot on Google and nothing found. Sorry for misunderstand question!

Comment: Cardano mainnet is functional. You can search for Plutus Pionner program and find some very good tutorials.

Comment: @raghu you mean Ada is still based on ETH mainnet?

Comment: No, it is totally independent. Nothing to do with ETH. Mainnet is working for last two years.

Comment: @raghu thank you, please post an an answer and I will mark it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cardano network was launched in 2017